# dict() Python for foreign language

Tags: python, dictionary

I make as bellow

```
mapper = {'А': 1, 'Б': 1}
mapper
```

or

```
mapper = {u'А': 1, u'Б': 1}
mapper
```

А, Б - Russians letters.
Both we have

```
{u'\u0410': 1, u'\u0411': 1}
```

Python 2.7

what is correct way? thanks

Comment: With Python 3 it makes no difference

Comment: sorry I've fogotten to tell i used 2.7

Comment: Then you can't get the same output in the two cases

Comment: Unless you are using `unicode_literals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3, all three approaches are the same.

With Python 2, things get tricky. You have to include an encoding at the top of your file (after the shebang line, if you have one) if you use either the first or the second approach, as otherwise Python will complain about you having non-ASCII characters in the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
```

If you use the first approach, your unicode text will be *encoded* with UTF-8:

```
>>> mapper == {'\xd0\x90': 1, '\xd0\x91': 1}
True
```

If you use the second approach, your unicode text will be interpreted as unicode text:

```
>>> mapper == {u'\u0411': 1, u'\u0410': 1}
True
```

Note that the two are very different. One is a string of bytes, while the other represents text:

```
>>> {'\xd0\x90': 1, '\xd0\x91': 1} == {u'\u0411': 1, u'\u0410': 1}
False
```

In either case, using character escape sequences or unicode literals doesn't make a difference, since they represent the same unicode character:

```
>>> u'\u0411' == u'Б'
True
```

You can make Python 2 behave like Python 3 by declaring a character encoding at the top of the file and importing `unicode_literals` from the `__future__` package:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

This will make your code work similarly in both Python 2 and Python 3.